# Do car dealerships check if a car needs recalled parts for free?

Tags: nissan, used

I'm looking to buy a used car (2003 Nissan Sentra) from a friend who also bought it used a couple years back. Since he bought it used he doesn't know the detailed history of the car. I looked online and I saw that the car has had several recalls issued. If I go to a Nissan dealership will they check all the parts of the car to make sure all the recalled ones have been swapped? If they do find that it has recalled parts would they replace them for for free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every jurisdiction that I know of, the answer is yes.  It is a legal requirement of the vehicle recall system.

If you give a dealer the VIN, they will be able to check if the vehicle ever had the recall work done.

If it hadn't, then the whole point of recalls is that the work is free to the owner.